# Java to ASN1 readable string

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1

We are working on a project in which I need to play with ASN1.
An we decided to use BC to to that.

There is a complex ASN1 definition file that I have to work with and so far so good, I am able to create my classes and use BC to do my sets, sequences, etc... This is going to take ages but we'll manage.
No problem for generation my DER TLV either.

What I would like to do is to be able to create a readable ASN1 String from my ASN1 object. By readable I man something like this: (example taken from [asn1 playground](https://asn1.io/asn1playground/))

```
value Rocket ::= {
  name "Falcon",
  -- use default for the message --
  fuel solid,
  speed mph : 18000,
  payload {
    "Car",
    "GPS"
  }
}
```

Is there a way of providing the relevant informartion in my Java Classes (like the attributes name, the name of the sequences attributes, etc...) and get that written into something readable like this?

Is there a BC method to do that or another library?

Answer (score 0):

So, we did not find anything easy on our side...
We ended up creating our own ASN1 Types and creating our own toASN1ReadbaleString() method for each of those.

This is a long and painful porcess that we are still in the middle of. Good luck for anyone with the same requirement (and who doesnt have the budget to buy Pro software!)